# If I ever compose minor key music, for the original key, should I use A minor or C minor?

Tags: composition, key-signatures

The A minor scale is the first and easiest minor key to learn in music since it has no sharps and flats just like its relative key called the C major scale but I've seen some composers like Grant Kirkhope used both C major and C minor as the main key for most of the songs from 2 of the Nintendo 64 games called Banjo Kazooie and Banjo Tooie since C major and C minor are parallel keys so I'm wondering should I use the A minor scale as the main key since it's the first minor scale to learn just like relatively the C major scale or should I use the C minor scale as the main key since it's the parallel of the first major scale called C major.

Comment: Which instrument(s) are you composing for?

Comment: I mean it doesn't matter what instruments.

Comment: It also doesn‘t matter in which key. Play it in both keys and write it in both keys. You will learn more and you’ll have the greatest profit.

Comment: @MatthewtheMusicFan2022 It does matter! C major is the easiest key on the piano, but not on every instrument. It's certainly not the easiest key on the violin, where G, D and A are arguably easier, and a beginner playing the trombone would probably prefer Bb, Eb, Ab or even Db major.

Comment: Considering that the reference is about a synthesized music played by a "program", the key is almost irrelevant as long as "it sounds good" with the chosen "instrument". But, as said, the instrument *does* matter if it's going to be played by somebody: certain instruments do not even have certain keys, cannot play some of them at the same time or cannot switch easily (consider the harp) or have a range that limits the available sounds based on the key (if the part uses a bigger range). The instrument must *always* be considered when composing, especially if the target musician is a beginner.

Comment: Indecisively flip between A minor and C minor, just like Kirby games do. Occasionally, indecisively flip between those two keys *in the same theme* (e.g. the *Kirby Squeak Squad* regular boss theme). As a result, also occasionally try a minor key other than those two (e.g. the regular boss theme of *Kirby's Return to Dream Land* being in F minor instead).

Comment: I mean in music softwares, not necessarily on actual instruments.

Comment: @MatthewtheMusicFan "should" implies that there might be an advantage to using one key over another.  Whether there's an advantage to a given key depends on what _you_ find advantageous, which is of course subjective.  What do you find advantageous?

Comment: I don't even know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...some composers like Grant Kirkhope...since C major and C minor are parallel keys so I'm wondering should I use the A minor scale as the main key since it's the first minor scale to learn...

It is natural to start learning minor keys using either `A` minor or `C` minor for the reasons you mention, but I don't really see the connection between your comment about Kirkhope, and what key you should choose.

But, I don't think that makes a difference. You could use any minor key `A`, `C`, etc. And you could try working in parallel key changes too if you want to emulate Kirkhope. You could look to other composers as well. (Haydn minuets often go to the parallel minor for the "trio" section is another example.)

Two caveats:

Regarding this comment...

> ...The A minor scale is the first and easiest minor key to learn in music since it has no sharps and flats...

...if you are working with standard minor key harmony, that really is not true. Research the dominant chord in minor, or the use of the raise sixth and seventh scale degrees in minor key music. In a nutshell, the seventh degree gets raised for dominant chords in minor, so for example, in `A` minor, the `E` chord will use a `G` sharp and so the chord will be an `E` *major* chord. For some practical examples try looking at those Haydn minuet trios I mentioned earlier, or any of the many short keyboard works of JS Bach, stuff like the "little preludes."

Second, it doesn't really matter which minor key you first choose to learn from. But try to learn all the minor keys. You can start with a small set at the beginning, like `A` minor with no sharps/flats, `D` minor with one flat, and `E` minor with one sharp.

If you are playing on keyboard, you may also want to start early with one minor key with tonic on a black key, like `F#` minor with only three sharps, but starting on a black key.

To learn a minor key probably, play with various forms of scales - natural, harmonic, and melodic. Most method books would have you just play the scales, but I think it's better to put them into a harmonic context to see how the various changes to the sixth and seventh degree actually work. For a dominant chord use the raised seventh degree, for a subdominant chord use the lowered sixth and seventh degrees, for a tonic chord it's a bit of a mix but a reasonable rule of thumb is probably to *not* use the lowered sixth and seventh for an ascending scale for a tonic chord.

[image]

...those are just a few basic examples, of course you could do many other things.

Getting the feel of minor keys can take a while, because of the variable sixth and seventh degrees. Just give it time and stick with it, it should make sense to your ears, and then it will make sense in your hands and on the page. Understanding this flexible use of scale tones will become very valuable knowledge.

Comment: I like the pun in your 1st sentence - intended or not...

Comment: Yeah, hear that in my head when I wrote it too :-)

Answer (score 1):

A minor has the parallel key of A major. Often pieces don't modulate into their parallel keys - not as often as into their relative keys, anyway.

Using C minor will incorporate 3 flats, against 0 for C major. Using A major will incorporate 3 sharps, against 0 for A minor. So it's as long as it's broad !

For simplicity, at the stage you seem to be at, stick with the key signature of C major/A minor - no ♯ or ♭.